# Python 3, and slice operand with comma

Tags: python

I came to a notation in python where I iterate len(nums) like this:
where

```
res = []
res += nums[i]
```

and I get the `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`
error message.
However, If I do,

```
res += nums[i],
```

the expression passes. I tried to look Python doc, but couldn't find the reference. Can you please help me locate it or explain why I need a comma for slice iteration additions?

Comment: what does nums have?

Comment: `nums[i]` is an `int` which is not iterable (as the error message says), whereas `nums[i],` is a `tuple`, which is iterable. What you probably wanted to do here was `res.append(nums[i])` - using `res += ...` is equivalent to `res.extend(...)` which means the right-hand side must be iterable.

Comment: It is not about the comma, but the variable `nums`. In the first instance variable `nums` must be an integer. So, it throws an error. In the second instance it must be `list`, therefore there won't be any error.

Answer (score 4):

Your `nums` list is probably a 1d list, let's say the list is:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
```

Then when you index the `nums` list:

```
nums[i]
```

It will give you a value of `1` or `2` or `3`.

But single values can't be added to a list:

```
>>> [] + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    [] + 1
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
>>>
```

But your second code works because adding a comma makes a single value into a tuple, like below:

```
>>> 1,
(1,)
>>>
```

So of course:

```
>>> res = []
>>> res += (1,)
>>> res
[1]
>>>
```

Works.

It doesn't only work with `,` comma, if you do:

```
>>> res = []
>>> res += [1]
>>> res
[1]
>>>
```

It will work too.

Comment: I have a question, why `[] + (1,)` gives an error?

Comment: I'll put that into another question

Comment: @ppwater Yeah go for it :-)

Comment: @ppwater I was going to ask but I have to get off PC so you can ask :-)

Comment: Done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546824/why-a-variable-and-just-list-results-are-different If anyone wants to see