# Why + and += is different?

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
numlist = [1,2,3]
```

But, I know I can't do this: `numlist += 1`.

Because it will raise a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

And I have to do `numlist += 1,` [So it will make a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546693/python-3-and-slice-operand-with-comma).

But then why?:

```
>>> numlist = [1,2,3]
>>> numlist += 1,
>>> numlist
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Doesn't give errors.

#### My question

I did it with a variable, but if I do:

```
[1,2,3] + 1,
```

I get

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Why if I do `list + 1,` then errors but if I do `variablecontainslist += 1,` then no errors?

And also,

```
[1,2,3] + (1,)
```

Gives

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

Comment: This is just because `+` has higher precedence than `,` but `+=` has lower precedence.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @kaya3: That's one of the things going wrong, but even if you added parentheses, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Compare e.g. `x = 1` and then `x *= 4 + 5` or `x * 4 + 5`. In the `*=` one it will do `4 + 5` before multiplying, in the other one it will do `x * 4` before adding.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, then how in this situation? There is errors if I add parentheses

Comment: That's because then you are trying to add/concatenate a tuple to a list, which is not allowed.

Comment: Ah, okay. So it's because of the precedence, but if I add parentheses then it gets a tuple, and I add/concatenate a tuple to a list, Which is not allowed...

Comment: If anyone answers, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: It has already been responded here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905008/why-must-python-list-addition-be-homogenous

Comment: Also, from the docs: "for lists, __iadd__ is equivalent to calling extend on the list and returning the list. That’s why we say that for lists, += is a 'shorthand' for list.extend"

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the info.

Comment: And to finish @Rysicin thought - `.extend` accepts any iterable, not just other lists.

Comment: @ppwater I’d just like to note that all the discussion about precedence is not relevant, but you probably gathered that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lack of symmetry here. When using a `list`, `x += y` is basically `x.extend(y)` and `extend` works with any iterable.

```
extend(self, iterable, /)
    Extend list by appending elements from the iterable.
```

But `x = x + y` is more restrictive. If `x` is a list, `y` must be a list also. The `list.__add__` method knows the size and structure of both objects, so it can create the new `list` efficiently. I'm not sure why the implementers didn't keep these same restrictions for augmented addition. But its easy to turn `__iadd__` into an `extend` and the functionality is cool.

As for `[1,2,3] + 1,`, this expression creates a tuple but it fails on the first element. Had this been an operation that doesn't fail, you'd get the tuple.

```
>>> [1,2,3] + [4],
([1, 2, 3, 4],)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just Try this:

```
x = []                 # empty list
x += "hello"           # iterates over the string and appends to list
print(x)               # ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

versus

```
x = []                 # empty list
x = x + "hello"        # TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

The `+=` operator invokes the `__ iadd__()` list method, while `+` one invokes the `__ add__()` one. They do different things with lists.
`+=` **adds a number to a variable, changing the variable itself in the process** (whereas + would not).

Comment: *They do different things with lists.* What? (Just curious)

Comment: It may be useful to compare `+=` to `.extend()`.

Comment: The fact that iadd mutates the list where add does not is not the reason for the difference.